# Third level of CSS menu doesn't display properly

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a three level menu. It works with two levels, however when I added a third level and hover over level 1, it displays level 2 and 3. How can I make it only display the third level when lis on level 2 are hovered over?

My html:

```
<div id="menuContainer">
<div id="menuwrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Two 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">One 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Two 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="admin.php">One 3</a>
            <ul>                    
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Two 5</font></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><font size="2">Three 1</font></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><font size="2">Three 2</font></a></li>                          

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><font size="2">Two 6</font></a>
                    <ul > 
                        <li><a href="#"><font size="2">Three 3</font></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><font size="2">Three 4</font></a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>       
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
/*MENU CSS */
#menuwrapper  {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2000;
}
/* for adding arrows to the menu items with sub menus YET TO IMPLEMENT*/
#menuwrapper li > a:after { 
    content: ' '; 
} 
#menuwrapper li > a:only-child:after { 
    content: ''; 
}   

/* We remove the margin, padding, and list style of UL and LI components */
#menuwrapper ul, #menuwrapper ul li, #menuwrapper ul li ul li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

/* We apply background color and border bottom white and width to 150px */
#menuwrapper ul li{
    background-color:#2d6aff;
    border-top:solid 1px black;
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* We apply the background hover color when user hover the mouse over of the li component */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover{
    background-color:#15357F;
    position:relative;

}

/* We apply the link style */
#menuwrapper ul li a{
    padding:5px 15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/**** SECOND LEVEL MENU ****/
/* We make the position to absolute for flyout menu and hidden the ul until the user hover the parent li item */
#menuwrapper ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;

}

/* When user has hovered the li item, we show the ul list by applying display:block, note: 150px is the individual menu width.  */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul{
    left:100%;
    min-width:283px;
    top:0px;
    display:block;
}

/* we apply different background color to 2nd level menu items*/
#menuwrapper ul li ul li{
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    border-left: 1px solid #999999;
    width:100%;
}

/* We change the background color for the level 2 submenu when hovering the menu */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover{
    background-color:#4cff00;
}

/* We style the color of level 2 links */
#menuwrapper ul li ul li a{
    color:#000000;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    width: auto;
}
/**** THIRD LEVEL MENU ****/
/* We make the position to absolute for flyout menu and hidden the ul until the user hover the parent li item */
#menuwrapper ul li ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;

}

/* When user has hovered the li item, we show the ul list by applying display:block, note: 150px is the individual menu width.  */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover > ul {

    min-width:283px;
    top:0px;
    display:block;
}

/* we apply different background color to 3rd level menu items*/
#menuwrapper ul li ul li ul {
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    border-left: 1px solid #999999;
    width:100%;
}


/* We style the color of level 3 links */
#menuwrapper ul li ul li ul li a{
    color:#000000;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please change #menuwrapper ul li:hover ul, to #menuwrapper ul li:hover > ul, so it will affect only its direct child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyz4r0cv/3/)

I added two lines of CSS in the end with playing with parent selectors :

```
#menuwrapper > ul > li:hover > ul { display: block; left: 0; }
#menuwrapper > ul > li:hover > ul ul { display: none; }
```